# Isotope portfolio filtering - how to open on specific category

Tags: javascript, html, filtering, jquery-isotope

I'm using Isotope filtering for a portfolio. I'm simply trying to set it up so that on specific pages it opens up with one of the filtered cateogries already selected.

No matter what I try, it opens up with 'All' selected, which shows all of the projects. Does anyone know of a way that it can be set to open on a specific category, and not all.

I'm using the HTML from here - https://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/docs/filtering.html

and linking to the isotope.js file that looks like this -

https://github.com/metafizzy/isotope/blob/master/js/isotope.js

Got a list with a set of categories that looks like this -

```
<ul class="list-inline filter">
<li class="active"><a href="#" data-filter="*">All </a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-filter=".education">Education</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-filter=".healthcare">Healthcare</a></li>
```

and when you select one of the categories it sorts the projects depending on what class has been applied to the div for the portfolio.

All I want is for it to open on one of the categories and not default to opening on ALL.

Comment: You need to provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Not sure what other details I can provide